# How to enable android vitals in google developer console?

Tags: android, developer-console

I am not able to see any data in my vitals overview section (ANR rate , Crash rate ... ) always the same message :

Sorry, this data is not available.

Are there any steps that i should go into to enable this feature ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to enable this feature. It is automatic.

This message appears most likely because you don’t have enough data for Google to calculate rates and show ANR/Crashes. Wait until there is more data and you will have it.

Comment: I have lots of crashes and ANR but don't understand why it still show 'Data unavailable'